# Friendly url with the same name of the files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I'm trying to use friendly url this way:

```
RewriteRule ^index/([1-9]{1,5})$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/([1-9]{1,5})$ /contact.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But this is not working and i think it's because i'm using the name of the file in the RegEx.

This works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^home/([1-9]{1,5})$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^emailus/([1-9]{1,5})$ /contact.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I did not know that is not possible to use the name of the file in the friedly urls, please, somebody knows a way to modify this configuration? In other case i'll have to change all the name of my files.

Comment: you can always turn on rewrite logging to see what's going on: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging level `trace3` will show the basic path through the rules and rewrite operations, allowing you to see HOW this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case of [Multiviews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) and mod_negotiation rearing its ugly head when its unwanted.

What's probably happening is that you have mod_negotiation seeing the request is `/contact/123` and notices that there is a `/contact.php` file, and then immediately serves that file and bypasses mod_rewrite entirely. You'll need to turn it off:

```
Options -Multiviews
```